# Como passar uma variável do tipo decimal para um comando sql do tipo string com o separador decimal "."?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net

Eu tenho a seguinte classe Model:

```
public class ModelTransaction
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe a data")]
        public string Date { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o valor")]
        public decimal Value { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe a descrição")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public TransactionType Type { get; set; }
        public ModelUser User { get; set; }
        public ModelAccount Account { get; set; }
        public ModelAccountingPlan AccountingPlan { get; set; }
    }
```

E tenho o seguinte método para acesso ao banco MySQL(comando UPDATE):

```
public void Update()
        {
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();

        string loggedIdUser = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("IdUsuarioLogado");

        sql.Append(" UPDATE Transacoes SET ");
        sql.Append($" Data_Transacao = '{Convert.ToDateTime(Date).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")}', ");
        sql.Append($" Tipo_Transacao = {ConvertHelpers.ToInt32(Type)}, ");
        sql.Append($" Descricao_Transacao = {Description}, ");
        sql.Append($" Valor_Transacao = {Value}, ");
        sql.Append($" Id_Conta = {Account.Id}, ");
        sql.Append($" Id_PlanoContas = {AccountingPlan.Id} ");

        sql.Append($" WHERE Id_PlanoContas = {Id}");
        sql.Append($" AND Id_Usuario = {User.Id}");

        DalFinances dalFinances = new DalFinances();
        dalFinances.ExecuteSql(sql.ToString());
    }
```

Antes de passar a minha variavel Value para o comando, o valor contido nela está com o separador decimal correto para o comando MySQL, ou seja, com o separador "." (ponto). 
Porém, ao passar esse valor para a string, o separador passa a ser a "," (virgula), fazendo com que não seja bem interpretado pelo MySQL. 
O servidor está rodando com as configurações de linguagem e globalização como pt-BR, e assim, utiliza a virgula como separador padrão.

Porém, existe algum jeito de 'burlar' essa questão, fazendo com que essa variavel seja passada com ponto, ao invés da virgula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use uma das sobrecargas do método [ToString](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tostring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads).

Você pode fazer:

```
sql.Append($" Valor_Transacao = {Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}, ");
```

ou então:

```
sql.Append($" Valor_Transacao = '{Value.ToString("0.00")}', ");
```